# Multiple Rabbit Connection Factory on Actuator Health Check

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am using spring boot 1.2.0.RELEASE.

I have an app that has multiple Rabbit Connection Factories, I want to add all of them to the actuator health, but I have not find an out-of-the-box solution for that.  I can extend the spring actuator to accomplish that but I want to avoid to reinvent the wheel but I have not been able to find a solution for that.